# TypeScript - Unable to create a "delete" function outside of a class

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

The problem I'm facing is that I am unable - outside of a class definition - to create functions with names that are the same as keywords.

This same "issue" occurs with other keywords, but `delete` is the keyword of interest here.

THIS WORKS:

```
    class WebServiceInterface {
        create(): void { }
        retrieve(): void { }
        update(): void { }
        delete(): void { }
    }
```

Notice that I have a function member named "delete".

BUT THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
    class WebServiceInterface {
        create(): void { }
        retrieve(): void { }
        update(): void { }
        delete(): void { }
    }

    module Web {

        var defaultInterface = new WebServiceInterface();

        export function create() { defaultInterface.create(); }
        export function retrieve() { defaultInterface.retrieve(); }
        export function update() { defaultInterface.update(); }
        export function delete() { defaultInterface.delete(); }
    }
```

The `delete` portion of `export function delete` causes these errors:

- Identifier expected.
- Expression expected.
- ';' expected.

Is there a fundamental reason why this couldn't/shouldn't be allowed? Is this perhaps just something that needs to be implemented in the language? Is there another way to achieve this?

---

For reference, I'm using TypeScript 1.4 inside of Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that delete is a reserved word in JavaScript.

The code generated with the delete block removed is:

```
var WebServiceInterface = (function () {
    function WebServiceInterface() {
    }
    WebServiceInterface.prototype.create = function () {
    };
    WebServiceInterface.prototype.retrieve = function () {
    };
    WebServiceInterface.prototype.update = function () {
    };
    WebServiceInterface.prototype.delete = function () {
    };
    return WebServiceInterface;
})();
var Web;
(function (Web) {
    var defaultInterface = new WebServiceInterface();
    function create() {
        defaultInterface.create();
    }
    Web.create = create;
    function retrieve() {
        defaultInterface.retrieve();
    }
    Web.retrieve = retrieve;
    function update() {
        defaultInterface.update();
    }
    Web.update = update;
})(Web || (Web = {}));
```

Guess what code it would try to generate when uncommenting the delete block?

```
    function delete() {
        defaultInterface.delete();
    }
    Web.delete = delete;
```

The problem is that is not valid JavaScript since delete is a reserved word.

Answer (score 8):

This little trick my help when you want to export `delete` named function directly from namespace/module, found [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fb3c5606ad782e7666febfd1d3f4829c15c4f92e/types/dot-prop-immutable/index.d.ts#L134). The `export as` is used to bypass the issue.

```
export default Package;

declare namespace Package {
    function _delete(...args: any[]): any;
    export { _delete as delete };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't name a *function* `delete`. It's a syntax error in JavaScript. Functions in modules are functions.

You *can* name a *property* `delete`. Methods in classes are properties of the prototype or instance, so it's valid there.

Answer (score 1):

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is a reserved word in Javascript, so you can't use it as the name of a function.

Beware if you use it as a property name, as I suspect that IE8 won't like that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue myself. The way you can get around this limitation is to declare the module as an object. A bit icky but it works.
EG:

```
declare var Web: WebServiceInterface;
```

Thus you end up with a variable called Web with the relevant functions on it.

Obviously if either `Web` or `WebServiceInterface` contain additional functions / properties you'll need to introduce an interface like this:

```
class WebServiceInterface {
    create(): void { }
    retrieve(): void { }
    update(): void { }
    delete(): void { }

    doOther()
    // etc
}

interface IWebObject {
    create(): void;
    retrieve(): void;
    update(): void;
    delete(): void;

    specialFunction(): void;
    defaultInterface: WebServiceInterface;
    // etc
}

declare var Web: IWebObject;
```